# Overload operator at runtime

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload a operator at runtime? I tried the following code example:

```
class A():
    pass
a = A()
a.__eq__ = lambda self, other: False
a == a # this should return False since the __eq__-method should be overloaded but it returns
       # True like object.__eq__ would
a.__eq__(a, a) # this returns False just as expected
```

Why won't this code work? Is it possible to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: IIRC, special "dunder" methods are always looked up on the _class_, not the instance.

Comment: @mgilson is right, try assigning to `A.__eq__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magic/double underscore methods are looked up on the class, not on the instance. So you need to override the class's method, not the instance. There are two ways to do this.

Either directly assign to the class as such:

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
A.__eq__ = lambda self, other: False
print(a == a)
print(a.__eq__(a)) # You're already passing in self by calling it as an instance method, so you only pass in the other one.
```

Or if you only have the instance and you're using 3.x, you can do:

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
type(a).__eq__ = lambda self, other: False
print(a == a)
print(a.__eq__(a))
```

Comment: Great, but I get an error when I try running a.__eq__(a) so I assumed that when you called the operator method you had to pass "self" as well. I get TypeError: eq() missing 1 required positional argument: other. Is there perhaps a difference between python2 and python3?

Comment: So then it is the difference between 2 and 3 because as I said, this dose not work in python 3, there the self argument need to be passed to the method.

Comment: It works in 3 as well. https://ideone.com/CvKI5n Are you calling it as `a.__eq__(a)` or `A.__eq__(a)`?

Comment: Yes I can see that it's working. Intresting. No I'm doing exactly as you are. I am using python 3.5

Comment: It seems to have something to do with Windows Python Shell. It works when I run it in the cmd but in the Python Shell I get the exception. Strange